# How to compile a kivy project with other libraries?

Tags: python, android, kivy, opencv

I just make a python file with kivy, cv2 and webcolors.
Watch this!

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.config import Config
import cv2
import webcolors
<My code>
```

I'm going to use Buildozer to compile these code to .apk file. 
But I think that Buildozer just compile only kivy Library.
So How to compile this code to .apk (using buildozer if you can)?
honestly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your buildozer.spec file

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy, kivymd, opencv, paho-mqtt
```

you can check the available recipes here:
[P4A receipes](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/develop/pythonforandroid/recipes)

If your package is pure python you do not need a recipe ex: paho-mqtt

If your package has C/C++ byndings you need a recipe ex: opencv

Comment: actually, I need Webcolors library too. But I didn't find this recipe. Now I'm nervous.

Comment: Don't be nervous, investigate and resolve the problem. In this case, you'll probably find that webcolors is a pure python library without special dependencies, and so needs no special treatment to work on android.

Comment: well actually, I must install webcolors on pycharm cuz I must convert RGB value to English Colour name.

Comment: so I don't need to install the Webcolors library???
By the way, webcolors is not one of pure python Libraries, I have just searched on Google.

Comment: If you are talking about this (https://github.com/ubernostrum/webcolors) i do not see any C/C++ bindings in there. Also you can just try to compile the app and see if is working. Make sure that you logcat the android to see what is going on.

Comment: Wait. I just read a book which is Talking about Kivy. And it says: "when you require a library, Buildozer will download for you". So is it right???

Comment: Yes it is. But if the library/package has C/C++ bindings those need a special recipe. Only pure python libraries will work 'out of the box'. The 'most used' libraries do have a recipe.

Comment: '''# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,opencv,webcolors --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21'''
How to solve?? I really need the solution now :(